# Trigger function PostgreSQL/PostGIS points within polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I wan't to update a column in PostgreSQL that counts the number of points inside a polygon using a trigger function. The function should be fired on each insert or update of the polygons or the points layer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.upd_points_in_polygons()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$ 
BEGIN
SELECT count(p.gid) INTO NEW.num_points FROM polygons po, points p WHERE st_intersects(NEW.the_geom, p.the_geom);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Here the trigger from the table polygons.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_upd_points_in_polygons
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON public.polygons
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.upd_points_in_polygons();
```

The column num_points isn't updated, but I don't see any errors?

Answer (score 2):

The trigger is set to be `AFTER insert`, so it is executed once the row has been inserted in the DB and it is too late to modify it. The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) says

> The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER [...] is always
>   ignored; it might as well be null.

To be able to alter the `NEW` record, you will want to change the trigger to a `BEFORE` trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_upd_points_in_polygons
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON public.polygons
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.upd_points_in_polygons();
```

**Edit** following your comment/other answer:

The query is also wrong, as you are referencing the `polygon` table without using it. The query is therefore making a cross-product between the `polygon` table and the intersection result, which is not desired. Should you be tempted to restrict polygon by `id`, the query will fail for inserts as the ID doesn't exist, and therefore the cross product will be empty.

To solve it, you can remove any reference to the `polygon` table, which is not needed as you have the `NEW` geometry.

```
SELECT count(p.gid) 
INTO NEW.num_points 
FROM points p 
WHERE st_intersects(NEW.the_geom, p.the_geom);
```

Comment: I changed the trigger to BEFORE insert, but still get no updates. So probably there is something wrong with my update string.

Answer (score 0):

OK, on pgAdmin 4 I had the problem, that the updates were only visible after saving and reloading the data.

I had to change my update string as well, so that it applies only to the actual row:

```
SELECT count(p.gid) INTO NEW.num_points 
FROM polygons po, points p 
WHERE st_intersects(NEW.the_geom, p.the_geom) 
AND po.gid = NEW.gid;
```

works fine now.
thanks for help.

Comment: This query will not work for inserts. See my updated answer